# How to host/upload .net webservice online (on IIS server)

Tags: .net, web-services, iis, hosting

I have created a .NET web service using C# and ASP.net
I like to upload or host it online, so that I pass the URL to my friends for use.
please help me with the steps of upload the web service.

Thanks a lot

regards

Kai

Comment: Right-click the project and use the "Publish" command.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of IIS you use, what sort of what application is it, and more stuff.

But basically, a right click and the publish command might work.

Some web hosting services don't let you reach their IIS remotely, these usually allow you to use FTP or something similar to upload your site.
If this is the case, publish to your local machine, and copy-paste to the server from there.

If you use data bases, you should also create the required database on the server.

You may also have to tweak your configuration (Web.config file) a little bit for the differences between the server and your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server with IIS on it. If you have a server already in place then you can just copy the published assemblies onto the web server and then use IIS to host the web service. You will also need a URL to make it available to your friends.